# Populate Container in SharePoint 2010 timeout

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-userprofile

I'm trying to connect the User Profile Service (UPS) to AD using an account with the proper permissions. When I click the Populate button, the AD forrest immediatly appears, but I cannot expand it. If I select the entire forest the process times out.

The error message on screen says it is a client machine time out. There are no entries in ULS or the server app or system logs.

I've tried upping the default 300 to 3600 in the web.config files which didn't help. I have the exact same setup in my test farm, which makes me wonder if the problem lies with the UPS.

Both UPS services are running, both FIMs are running

Comment: Problem solved! Turns out there is a local security policy for LDAP that was set to Negotiate and should have been off.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! Turns out there is a local security policy for LDAP that was set to Negotiate and should have been off.